# Label doesn't change when language change while app running

Tags: android, android-layout, localization

I have a bit weird problem with changing languages in Android.
When I switch the device language and open the app - all works well. 
But when the app still running and I change the device language - a single string (label of checkBox) won't change, and the same for changing from the second language to the first while the app running. If I restart the app - all works well again.

It happens for both orientations (I have a different layout for the landscape one).

I tried to check if it was because the change was because of the second language is Hebrew (so the direction of the language is reversed) so I added French (with a bit different strings from English) but it didn't work as well.

I also tried to add `checkBox.setText(getString(R.string.ChkBox));` in `onCreate` but it didn't work.

Comment: It would be far easier to help you if you posted your code of where you're setting your text fields. If you only do it in `onCreate()` and you come back to the app after, it'll skip `onCreate()` and go to `onResume()` as part of activity lifecycle. This is why you only see the change when you reset the app, because `onCreate()` will be executed again.

Comment: i didn't post my code because i didn't change the label of this checkBox at all after declaring the checkBox and the string it shows:

`<CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/foodChkBox"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />`
in the java files, i am only checking the checkBox's status

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a dupe of the question [onConfigurationChange not called after changing locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725396/onconfigurationchange-not-called-after-changing-locale)

You will need to add the following to your activity definition in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"
```

This way, onConfigurationChange is called for locale (Language) changes. Then, you can override onConfigurationChange in your activity and make sure that you're setting the text properly.

Note that there is some additional work required to get your strings.xml to work with translations / different locales. You can use the Android Studio translation helper to make it easier.

Comment: does it means that onConfigurationChange he should set every single text again of this view again?

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose of onConfigurationChanged - you are listening for the rare event where a user is switching the language of their device. If you don't want a user to have to reload the activity manually, then switching the text in onConfigurationChange is preferable. Your solution of killing the activity and restarting it is wasteful of resources and unnecessary. He can encapsulate all of the logic for the view initialization in a single method, and call that from onConfigurationChanged (as well as onCreate), or he could put the text setters in the onResume step.

Comment: it means that android:text is useless if you need to change the language because you should set every single text manually, isn't it?

Comment: i don't think that's the problem because the locale did change  - all the other labels and strings did change to the new locale, except this one.
also, i do have the suggested line in the manifest, and it does not help...
i tried to remove `locale` from it (so and got the same results

Comment: Do you have locale specific strings? Chances are that the other locale string key is misspelled or absent?