# API to read user's locale settings on Android

Tags: android

I am trying to see if there is any API I can use to read the user's settings like date/time etc on Android device. If the user selects 24 hour format or changes any other setting, I should be able to know about it.

Any info on this will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By locale you mean language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android get current Locale, not default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389349/android-get-current-locale-not-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no all encompassing API to gather user settings. You will need to query a few different APIs to get what you need.

One is `Device`

```
Device.getLocale()
Device.getScreenSize()
```

is the common way to get the current locale setting.

If you want to get an update when the user changes it you could try a broadcast receiver like in this answer:

[Android - Listening to a locale change without static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239551/android-listening-to-a-locale-change-without-static-variables)

You can access the user date preferences via DateFormat.

```
DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)
```

Comment: Thank you Cory. I am looking for something like an API for reading user settings.

Comment: @user4122421 Added some notes about date settings